# Can a HTML5 web application access the camera on a Windows 7 tablet

Tags: html, windows-7

I have a HTML/Javascript web application which integrates with a device's camera using PhoneGap.

Is there any way we can run the application on a Windows 7 tablet (e.g. as a normal website) and be able to integrate with the camera on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be, eventually, when the getUserMedia API is implemented in more browsers (currently only available in Opera and special builds of other browsers), but at the moment, no.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to do this.

We enabled photos to be dragged into the application to support this feature.  It means the user takes a photo as dictated by the tablet and then has to drag/select the appropriate photo file to add to the application.